# Fuse Fabric8 Clustering

Tags: automation, docker, cluster-computing, fabric8

I am noob in fabric8. I have a doubt regarding clustering with docker images.

I have pulled the docker image for fabric8 `fabric8/fabric8`. I just want to make the containers i launch to automatically fall into the same cluster without using `fabric:create` and `fabric:join`.

Say if i launch 3 containers of `fabric8/fabric8` they should fall under the same cluster without manual configuration.

Please give some links are references. I'm lost.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In fabric8 v1 the idea was that you create a fabric, using the fabric:create command and then you spin docker container, using the docker container provider in pretty much the same way as you were doing with child containers (either using the container-create-docker command or using hawtio and selecting docker as the container type).